# How can I access Windows 10 if I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10 but it is not shown in boot options?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, windows-10

I natively had Windows 10 on my SAGER gaming laptop. However, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside windows 10. I cannot access Windows upon reboot as it is not shown in grub/boot options.

Here's what I see in GParted. Is there any hope I could still access Windows or the data on it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see Ubuntu.  All I see is Windows, MS partitions and the EFI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix) or [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/286181/) I think the first link is the true duplicate because you have Windows 10 installed on `/dev/nvme0n1p4`

Comment: What does show up in your grub/boot options?  I wonder if your Ubuntu.iso is corrupted.  Did you verify your ISO?

Comment: The Microsoft Reserved is a required small unformatted partition that needs to be before main Windows partition. Since unformatted it often shows as an error. Order on drive is important: msftres
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition  Can you boot Windows directly from UEFI boot menu, often f12, but varies by vendor?

Comment: @Nmath I wrote this post from Ubuntu. My question is why at the boot time I can only boot to Ubuntu and can't boot to Windows?

Comment: @hoatzin only Ubuntu

Comment: Unless you have another hard drive, I don't see how it's possible that Ubuntu is installed. Did you remove the installation media? Please read the links that were shared with you, make some attempts to fix this using those links, and if you still are lost, come back and edit your question with the details.  Right now you've presented an impossible situation. You're incorrect about something you've posted - or you're missing info. We need a whole and accurate picture to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your "Gparted" data, there is no Ubuntu OS installed, and no free space for you to install it.

1. Windows Task: Free some space (say 100G from the Windows "Basic data partition"), using Windows "Disk Management" -- shrink it! And you should be able to see the availbale free space. From my (limited) experience, you don't even need to format it.
2. Ubuntu task: Boot your system through a bootable Ubuntu USB disk; follow the prompt. And let Ubuntu do the rest, including fixing your boot up sequence.

It worked for me. Hope it does for you too. Good luck.

Comment: Well, this is wrong since I wrote this post from my Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

Download a fresh Ubuntu ISO and perform the checksum verification. Reinstall Ubuntu using the new verified ISO image.  A successful installation of Ubuntu would resolve your booting issues.  There is probably nothing wrong with your Windows10.